# AWS and Direct Connect

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm having some trouble with a few hosts in AWS and a recently setup Direct Connect.  I was hoping to achieve the following goal:

1. Advertise my networks to AWS via the direct connect - I got this working
2. Receive the public IP (elastic ip) back into our network via the direct connect - not working

The reason for wanting to achieve number 2 is that I want to ensure traffic on our network heading towards our servers within AWS takes the path - and that is to route traffic to the AWS public IP via a direct connect.  However, I'm not receiving the routes and I'm starting to think that this isn't possible.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to achieve what I'm after?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should receive all public IP prefixes from Amazon as described here: **[Using Public Virtual Interfaces](https://aws.amazon.com/directconnect/faqs/#Using_Public_Virtual_Interfaces)**. Most notably:

> You will receive all Amazon IP prefixes for the region that you are connecting to in supported AWS Regions

Are you sure you created a *Public* VIF?

Do you have any BGP filters on your side that perhaps kill the public prefixes?

Hope that helps :)

Comment: I just checked and it looks like it might be a private VIF - I'll change it over and set it up again.   Thanks for your help